# JQuery reproducing onmouseenter logic inline at element level

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very large HTML page whereby an enterprise user is displaying thousands of database records as part of a batch-update/validation process.

Within the page I need to add tooltips to many of the elements.  Previously we have used the trusty approach of doing this in the `<head>`:

```
$("elementID").mouseenter(function(){
    // tool tip logic
    // goes here
});
```

The problem is that this is adding tens of thousands of lines of JavaScript and causing massive performance problems.  So, I am researching the differences of applying this at element level instead.  So rather than having the above code for each element that requires a tooltip, I am declaring a single script block like this:

```
function ShowTooltip(ctrl, tooltip) {
    var o = $(ctrl).offset();
    var y = o.top;
    var x = o.left;
    $("#ttfloat").css({ top: o.top, left: o.left });
    $("#ttfloat").html(tooltip);
    $("#ttfloat").show();
}

function HideToolTip() {
    $("#ttfloat").hide();
}
```

And then firing this using the following approach for each respective element:

```
<div id="ttfloat">&nbsp;</div>
<p>Tool tip <span id="lbl1" runat="server" onmouseover="ShowTooltip(this, 'Tip Text');" onmouseout="HideToolTip();">appears here</span></p>
```

The problem is that when hovering over the `<span>` elements, there is a flicker of the tooltip element as the browser fires `onmouseover` repeatedly.  I read on other SO solutions that JQuery mouseenter is the way to go to solve this, but can only find examples that wire up the events in the head.  Can it be done in-line in the element, or is there a better way altogether?  The solution must work with older browsers and be standards compliant.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szCU2/1/)

Comment: Why not use jQuery UI's Tooltip widget? http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: Good suggestion, however, the overhead of those extra files (css/js) are huge.  I'd rather keep this simple and lightweight if possible.

Comment: The jQueryUI site lets you download a custom version that doesn't use a theme and that only includes the minimum for the tooltip widget to work - the min.js version for that is only 8kb. (If you want to make it even smaller just have a look yourself at how it works...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
<span data-tooltip-text="Tip text here">blah blah</span>
```

And then:

```
$("[data-tooltip-text]").on({
    mouseenter : function() {
      var o = $(this).offset();
      var tooltip = $(this).attr("data-tooltip-text");
      $("#ttfloat").css({ top: o.top, left: o.left })
                   .html(tooltip)
                   .show();
    },
    mouseleave : function() {
      $("#ttfloat").hide();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/szCU2/2/

I'd suggest you offset the vertical position of the tooltip a little bit, so that it doesn't completely cover the element that you're hovering over (which is clunky looking, and can potentially cause a mouseleave event since the mouse is then over the tooltip):

```
o.top + 18; // or whatever offset works for you
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/szCU2/3/

Comment: This doesn't work (at all) in IE10.  In Firefox, it still has the flickering problem I described originally!

Comment: I only tested it in Chrome, where the first version flickered if I kept moving the mouse around over the tooltip, but the second version with the offset tooltip didn't flicker at all. Regardless, the concept of using a `data-` attribute and not an inline `onwhatever=` handler should work fine for the not-repeating-lots-of-code part of the problem. If your original code (that you don't show) with `$("elementID").mouseenter(...` works without flickering then just adapt it to use the data attribute selector `$("[data-tooltip-text]")` instead of the element ID selector...

Comment: I just tried in IE10 - for some reason it _does_ work if I change it to jQuery 1.9: http://jsfiddle.net/szCU2/4/ but not, as you pointed out, with the original jQuery 1.10. (I don't have time to figure out the difference.)

Comment: So I'd do a search for all elements containing the attribute `data-tooltip-text` and then pull that value into the tooltip, right?

Comment: Exactly. That's what my code above does, and that part works fine, it's just the display/flickering that you're not happy with. (And the weird IE10 version of jQuery problem.) That part is more or less what Mike suggested in his answer, too.

Comment: That's pretty much what I need.  I can mess about with all the size and positioning later.  I forked it to use the TITLE attribute to enforce standards compliance on older browsers, which works really well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the behavior is the same in all of them, you should use a class selector instead of an id selector and simply add that class to all of your divs.  Then you just need that code once rather than having a copy of it for every single div.  Store the data somewhere useful (like a custom attribute for the div) and use that in your code.

html:

```
<div id="blah" class="divWithTooltip" data-custom-attribute="some tooltip text">
```

javascript:

```
$('.divWithTooltip')
    .on('mouseenter', function() {
      someMethodToDoYourTooltipStuff( $(this).attr('data-custom-attribute') );
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
       someMethodToHideYourTooltip();
    });
```

Comment: Are custom attributes allowed in standards compliant XHTML/HTML5?

Comment: Yeah, custom attributes simply need to be named in the data-<whatever> style.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes)